# Displaying collection of data within collection in rdlc

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have two tables in my database namely Employees and TimeLogs. Basically I want to create a Daily time record using rdlc. So, what I wanted is to display each employees' time logs.

Like:
[image: Daily Time Record Sample]

I tried to list within a list but it doesn't work. Tried subreport within a table, but I get errors. Tried list within a subreport that's within a list.

Can some one have a much better way of doing it?

Comment: btw, i'm using VS2010.

Comment: I also tried this link.. http://forums.asp.net/p/1432888/3224866.aspx#3224866 but it doesn't work in VS2010

Comment: This calls for simple table grouped by Employee.

Answer (score 0):

In [Tablix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220587.aspx) you can add [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx) to organize your data.

In your case you can group by employee and display times as details.